# Identify FLCL Japanese Fonts?

Tags: typography, font-identification, japanese

Can anyone help me identify these Japanese fonts of FLCL? I have tried several font identification services, but they don't seem to recognize Japanese symbols.

[image]

Comment: I just did a quick research "フリクリ フォント" in Japanese, but returning no result all... not sure if there is any published information about the official font. However, I'm not used to searching for modified font (if they are indeed modified).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for your assistance and information friend! I'm currently still trying to find the fonts (or Modified fonts) from the logo.

Answer (score 2):

Although the logo's glyph is too featureless to know whether it is based on an existing typeface, I could say from a purely geometric standpoint that it resembles [Astro](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/mksd_astro.html) and [Abstract](http://cute-freefont.flop.jp/abstract.html) most.

[image]
[image]